# How to retrieve References field using microsoft graph REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

Previously I used Microsoft EWS API to retrieve emails. It has a field called "References", now I am upgrading to MS Graph and couldn't find this particular field via REST API. Note that I could find and retrieve all other fields except this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The References property is just the References Message header so you get that header as part of the IntenetMessageHeaders https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/AAMkADhAAAW-VPeAAA=/?$select=internetMessageHeaders
```

You can also request the underlying Extended Mapi property PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES also eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x1039')
```

Comment: Thanks Glen, will check and respond back as needed

Comment: Thanks @Glen Scales  it helped me to send and receive customArgs.